# How to get Session value which is an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

I have a session set in a php page which stores an array as follows:

firstpage.php

```
   $_SESSION["Counts"]=$some_array;
   echo print_r($_SESSION["Counts"]);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [Finance] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 [2] => 0 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 ) 
[Human resources] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 5 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 )
[Infrastructure] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 3 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 0 ) ) 1
```

Retrieving the session data in .js page
SecondJSpage.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var sessionValue= new Array();
var s= new Array();
var s1= new Array();

sessionValue = '<?php $_SESSION["Counts"]; ?>';
document.write(sessionValue);   //Does not output anything

for( s1 in sessionValue) {
for( s in s1) {

    document.write(s);     //Does not output anything
    document.write("<br />");
}}
</script>
```

Only arrays are not being retrieved. A simple session variable is getting displayed. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line up a little bit..

```
sessionValue = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION["Counts"]); ?>;
```

Comment: it's okay...i do not want to echo there any way..just initialize

Comment: @AishwaryaR this is how you echo an array for javascript. try it.

Comment: Wasn't me (we all got whacked), but I'm guessing it's because your answer isn't actually *valid*. In a javascript file like OP's (SecondJSpage.js), your answer will not parse for obvious reasons (being that PHP does not parse within a .js file, unless you work some magic in the backend but I'm doubting OP did that). I'm just going off exactly what OP wrote in his initial post: "Retrieving the session data in .js page SecondJSpage.js"

Comment: @Marcus - I didn't notice that, but i did notice the `<script>` tags, which don't go in a .js file. When user contradicts himself believe the code before you believe the description..

Comment: I saw that as well. Seeing `<script>...</script>`, as you stated, would typically mean the JS is embedded in the PHP (makes sense). But reading *exactly* what OP wrote about it being in a separate .js file sent me down a different path in my thinking. But who knows what's really up with his code. He accepted your answer as *working*, so you were probably right in that it was actually in the PHP and not in a separate .js file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_encode()` for this purpose (Javascript can handle JSON).

Check the manual: http://php.net/json_encode

Comment: the J and the S in JSON stand for Javascript ;P

Comment: @Pamblam: Yes, exactly, I just wanted to clarify that for the user. :)

Comment: json_encode() worked. But is it okay to use php in javascript...?

Comment: Yes, sure it's okay, you just add additional text to your HTML output.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot `echo` an array.

```
<?php echo $_SESSION["Counts"]; // this is an array ?>
```

And you can't execute PHP within a .js file either (trying to parse PHP within SecondJSpage.js)

Comment: Yaa because php is server side scripting..is this not a valid way to get sessions?Then how am i supposed to use sessions in js?

Comment: You can *inline* the javascript so it's embedded within your PHP file (firstpage.php). But you can't create a separate .js file and execute PHP within that.